# How to check in a custom constraint validator whether a field allows for multiple values or not

Tags: 9, plugins

In my custom validator plugin I want to be able to tell whether the field value given was part of a field that allowed for more than 1 value.

For example

```
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
    if(<if field is a multivalue field>){
       $count = $items->count();
    } else {
       $count = $items->value;
    }
```

However I'm not sure how to tell whether a field allowed for multiple values in this function.

I tried the [getSettings()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/function/FieldItemList%3A%3AgetSettings/8.2.x) function but there didn't seem to be an allowed values setting displayed in the result.

How would I get the number of allowed values in a field?

Comment: You would want to check its cardinality property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the cardinality of the field. This is not a field setting, though, this is a field storage definition:

```
$cardinality = $items->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getCardinality();
```